# Build a query to assign trainings to staff

Tags: ms-access

This question has been updated since I originally posted it, thanks to the help from the initial respondent, I have made some progress but am still not quite there and can't figure out the following.

I have a list of staff who are assigned roles. Each roll is required to complete a different set of trainings. Sessions are recorded with a form which inputs to a table called "TrainingSessions". I want to take a list of names from the "Employees" table and compare it to the attendance from "TrainingSessions" and output a list of people who have not attended a session for a required training.

I have successfully created a query that pulls staff names (and associated ID) and lists it with the trainings that are required for the role that they are assigned.

```
SELECT Employees.ID, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName, Trainings.ID, Trainings.TrainingTitle
FROM (EmployeeRoles INNER JOIN Employees ON EmployeeRoles.ID = Employees.Role) INNER JOIN Trainings ON EmployeeRoles.ID = Trainings.RequiredFor.Value
GROUP BY Employees.ID, Employees.LastName, Employees.FirstName, Trainings.ID, Trainings.TrainingTitle, Employees.Resignation
HAVING (((Employees.Resignation) Is Null));
```

I've also created a query that flattens out the TrainingSessions so that each attendee is listed on their own line.

```
SELECT TrainingSessions.TrainingTitle AS Title, TrainingSessions.SessionDate AS [Date], TrainingSessions.Attendance.Value AS Who, DateAdd("yyyy",[Trainings]![YearsValid],[SessionDate]) AS Due
FROM Trainings INNER JOIN TrainingSessions ON Trainings.ID = TrainingSessions.TrainingTitle
ORDER BY TrainingSessions.SessionDate;
```

What I need now is to figure out how to compare the required trainings with those that have been completed and spit out a list of staff who haven't completed a particular training. The closest I've been able to get so far has been a list a trainings that are required by each employee that have never had a session entered instead of trainings that a particula staff hasn't attended.

Here's some pics of what my database looks like right now:

[image: RequiredTrainingsByEmployee]

[image: TrainingSessions]

[image: Employees]

[image: Relationships]

Comment: Can you show the three tables that you are starting with?  From that, you should be able to prepare lists of required training and completed training, and then compare the 2 lists.  Seeing what you have so far will help.

Comment: Try using the Access query builder Find Unmatched query wizard.

Comment: I added pics of the tables to the question. I am aware that two of the tables have multi-valued lookup field, I couldn't figure a way around that though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it!!!

First: I created a query that outputs a flat table that places all the trainings required for each employee on a separate line:

```
SELECT TrainingRequiredByName.Employees.ID AS EmpID, TrainingRequiredByName.Trainings.ID AS TrainID, TrainingRequiredByName.Employees.LastName AS [Last], TrainingRequiredByName.Employees.FirstName AS [First], TrainingRequiredByName.Trainings.TrainingTitle AS Title
FROM TrainingRequiredByName;
```

Then I created a query that outputs a flat table that places all the completed trainings on a separate line:

```
SELECT Employees.ID AS EmpID, Trainings.ID AS TrainID, Employees.LastName AS [Last], Employees.FirstName AS [First], Trainings.TrainingTitle AS Title
FROM Trainings INNER JOIN (Employees INNER JOIN TrainingSessions ON Employees.ID = TrainingSessions.Attendance.Value) ON Trainings.ID = TrainingSessions.TrainingTitle;
```

Then I did a find unmatched query that compares the EmpID and TrainID on each query and outputs the list that I have been searching for!

[image: The sought-after result]

Thank you Don George for helping move me in the right direction on this. I can't tell you how excited I am to have gotten a result that I can actually use!

Comment: Great!  I know the feeling, and glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have more problems than just this query.  First, the employee names in TrainingSessions don't appear to be consistent - some only have last name, some have last & first name.  It's not clear that they will match up with the Employee table.  Second, The RequiredFor field in Trainings look like it lists with multiple values in some cases - so the match to Employees isn't clear.  I assume it should match the Role field, and that the Role will always match the spelling, etc in the Trainings table - but it's still an extra step to extract them from a list.  Third, you have a YearsValid field in Trainings, so  assume you will need to not only check attendance but the dates as well - also not in your question.  Fourth, you have notes in TrainingSessions that say "Not a course taken" - do they need to be excluded?

So to get started, I think you'll need to think about building three queries.

First is the list of required courses.  You'll need to end up with a table that has something like the employee (preferably with the ID, not just the name) and the required course (again, with the course ID) and probably the YearsValid information.  Probably need 1 record per requirement per employee - not multiple requirements in one record.  This isn't too hard to assemble from the data you have, as long as the Role in Employees matches the Role in Trainings.  Save this as TrainingRequired.

```
SELECT Employees.ID AS EmployeeID, Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, Employees.Role, Trainings.ID AS TrainingID, Trainings.TrainingTitle, Trainings.YearsValid
FROM Employees, Trainings
WHERE (((InStr([RequiredFor],[Role]))>0));
```

Then you'll need another query for completed courses.  Assuming that employee last names are unique and that the TrainingSessions table includes at least the correct last name, something like this would work.  Note that this is a pretty poor assumption in most cases, so you may need a different way to get the employee ID into this query.  I also made no adjustments for the information in the Notes column.  Save this as TrainingCompleted.

```
SELECT Employees.ID AS EmployeeID, Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, Employees.Role, TrainingSessions.TrainingTitle AS TrainingID, TrainingSessions.SessionDate, TrainingSessions.Attendance
FROM Employees, TrainingSessions
WHERE (((InStr([Attendance],[LastName]))>0));
```

Once these 2 queries are both working properly and have both the EmployeeID and TrainingID, you can put them together to get what you need.

```
SELECT TrainingRequired.EmployeeID, TrainingRequired.FirstName, TrainingRequired.LastName, TrainingRequired.Role, TrainingRequired.TrainingID, TrainingRequired.TrainingTitle, TrainingCompleted.SessionDate, IIf((Now()-[SessionDate])/365<=[YearsValid],"X") AS [Current]
FROM TrainingRequired LEFT JOIN TrainingCompleted ON (TrainingRequired.TrainingID = TrainingCompleted.TrainingID) AND (TrainingRequired.EmployeeID = TrainingCompleted.EmployeeID);
```

This final query checks each requirement to see if the course has been taken and is still within the YearsValid criteria.  If so, the last column is "X".  If not, the last column is blank.  You can filter further on this to see only the missing requirements if you need to.

Comment: I'll give this a try. The multi-value lists in my tables have (since after I posted these pics) been converted to text lists, which now display the associated keys in the tables. The Required for field is related to the ID in the roles table (which I didn't show). the attendance field is related to the ID field in the employee table (which I didn't show). The "Not a course taken" is simply there as I was playing with the idea of just manually adding a training date in order to produce a due date. 

Thank you for your input. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: good - sounds like some minor changes to what I provided should get you what you need.  Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: I got an error right off the bat. It says the multi-valued field 'required for' cannot be used in a WHERE or HAVING clause. So, the multi-valued fields are the problem, but I don't know how to get around using multi-valued fields.

Comment: Changed the pic in the question to show how the trainings table now displays after changing the combo-box to text-box

Comment: Sorry for all the comments, but I noticed that some of my tables may not have been behaving correctly because of the way I eliminated the lookups in them. I have re-built the database (with less information in it now) and hopefully the way I've done it this time makes it work better. I've updated the pics to reflect the new database.

Comment: That version of Trainings actually makes it harder.  First of all, I haven't used multivalue fields so I can't help you there - but it sounds like you changed them to text fields anyway.  But with numbers in the RequiredFor field, I'm not sure how to search for a particular Role.  If Role=1, for example, it will match if RequiredFor is 1, but will also match if RequiredFor is 10. I'll have to think about this some more - if I come up with any better ideas, I'll check back in tomorrow.

Comment: are you familiar with VBA code?  It may be necessary, or at least useful, to write a short script to process the tables & separate the values.

Comment: I am not. I'm just learning Access now. The numbers being displayed in the tables are the keys associated with all the items. In my forms, you can see the text value for the associated key.

Comment: I cannot solve this for you - but I found another link that may be helpful.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a#bm1.  In this document, look for "Displaying the individual values in a multivalued field".  I think this may be what you will need to use to create queries like the ones I called TrainingRequired and TrainingCompleted.  Sorry I cannot take this any further.

Comment: I appreciate the effort!

Comment: I've made some progress. I wonder if you might take a look at what I have now and see if there's any suggestions. If not, I understand and still appreciate your help as it has gotten me this far.